# PHP currency converter

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the yahoo currency converter API to convert the currency for each product listed on the database when it's being displayed on the page.

**Function One**

```
        function currencyConverter($currency_from,$currency_to,$currency_input){
            $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
            $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("'.$currency_from.$currency_to.'")';
            $yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
            $yql_query_url .= "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
            $yql_session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
            curl_setopt($yql_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $yqlexec = curl_exec($yql_session);
            $yql_json =  json_decode($yqlexec,true);
            $currency_output = (float) $currency_input*$yql_json['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];

            return $currency_output;
        }
```

**Function two**

```
  function getProducts($currency)
  {
    if ($result = $connection->query("SELECT `name`, `price` FROM `products`")) {

      $product_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if ($product_count >0) {
        $output = ""; 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $price = currencyConverter("USD", $currency, $row['item_price']);
          $output = $output."<div class='item'><h3 class='product-name'>".$row['item_name']."</h3><h3 class='product-price'>".$currency." ".$price."</h3></div></div>";
        }
        echo $output;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      } else {
         echo "nope";
      }
    } else {
      echo "failed";
    }   
  }
```

The price of a product is saved in USD on the database. The problem is that it takes a very long time for it to convert each and every price. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: which bit takes the most time?

Comment: I just realized that I can get the conversion rate using currencyConverter() function just once and then do the math within the while loop, instead of calling the currencyConverter() function through each iteration.

Comment: @nadz I'd bet money your slowest line is the call to `curl_exec` since you're waiting on Yahoo's servers.  So yes, if you can call that just once and cache the result, everything else will speed up significantly.

Comment: just call it once a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working a lot faster now.

```
    if ($result = $connection->query("SELECT `name`, `price` FROM `products`")) {

      $product_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if ($product_count >0) {
        $output = ""; 
        // get current currency rate
        $exchange_rate = currencyConverter("USD", $currency, "1");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $price = $row['item_price'] * $exchange_rate;
          $output = $output."<div class='item'><h3 class='product-name'>".$row['item_name']."</h3><h3 class='product-price'>".$currency." ".$price."</h3></div></div>";
        }
        echo $output;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      } else {
         echo "nope";
      }
    } else {
      echo "failed";
    }
```

Comment: faster still, call it daily and store the results

Answer (score 1):

**try these**:

```
// google API - Load time: 558 ms
function google_money_convert($from, $to, $amount)
{
    $url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$from.$to;
    $request = curl_init();
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    preg_match('~<span [^>]* id="knowledge-currency__tgt-amount"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>~si', $response, $finalData);
    $finalData=str_replace(',', '.', $finalData);
    return (float)$finalData[1]*$amount;
}


 // free.currencyconverter API - Load time: 95ms
    function money_convert($from, $to, $amount)
{
    $url = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=$query&compact=ultra";
    $request = curl_init();
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $responseOld=$response;
    // print_r($response);
    return $response[$query]*$amount;
}
```